# In what mode are files opened in Scala Files IO?

Tags: scala

Python file handling function takes mode as optional parameter which for default is "r" (read).

```py
open(file, mode) #where mode by default is "r"
```

What is the Scala's analogous default for the same ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of using the concise one-liner method `scala.io.Source.fromFile`, file is opened in `read` mode, even if the same method is used to get reference to the buffered source.
Besides, to write `TXT` files we use Java fallbacks of `PrintWriter` or `FileWriter`, which opens files in `write` mode. Hence the "default" depends on whether we are writing to the file or reading from it.

I figured this by filtering the open files with `lsof` after opening file in sbt console, any productive additions and/or corrections are appreciated.